# Methods from Mongooose Subdocuments Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given the particular context I'm in, the methods attached to the subdocuments aren't being found. When I stop the code with a debugger statement, and access 'game.players[0].token() -- a method attached to the playerStatus child schema, I get:

"TypeError: Object # has no method 'turn'".

Here is the code:
PlayerStatus.js

```
// Player Status model
var Card = require('./card.js');

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var playerStatusSchema = new Schema({
  // user:    Object,
  user_id:   String,
  firstName: String,
  game_id:   String,
  deck:      [Card.getSchema() ],
  hand:      [Card.getSchema() ],
  discard:   [Card.getSchema() ],
  turnTokens: Array,
  buys:       Number,
  actions:    Number,

});

playerStatusSchema.methods = {

  turn: function() {
    return this.turnTokens[this.turnTokens.length-1];
  },

...
playerStatusSchema.statics = {
  getSchema: function() {
    return this.playerStatusSchema;
  }
};
module.exports = mongoose.model('PlayerStatus', playerStatusSchema);
```

And the part of the code where I'm accessing the subdocuments' methods:

```
var PlayerStatus = require('../models/playerStatus.js');
var Game         = require('../models/game.js');
var User         = require('../models/user.js');
...

exports.purchase = function(req, res) {
this.gameId          = req.body.gameId;
this.userId        = req.body.userId;
this.card            = req.body.card;
this.treasureCardIds = req.body.treasureCardIds;

Game.findById(this.gameId, _und.bind(function(err, game) {
  if (err) return err;
  debugger;
  game.players[0].turn();
```

The funny thing is that from within the Game document, I can call a player subdocument object and use those player's methods just fine. But in this case I'm in a controller class, not a parent class of the document.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: Where is your "turns" field in this schema? I don't see one.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, turns should be turnsTokens. I've changed the code and I'm still getting the same problem:"TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'turns'"

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I'm still at a loss on why this isn't working.